# quoting in pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, latex

I am outputting a csv file from pandas with some survey text for use in a latex report. Some of the responses have commas in their responses so pandas outputs the data as

```
"test data, some more data", some text, some more text
```

By wrapping the field in double quotes it is clearly then able to handle the comma in the field.

I would like the above to instead look like this:

```
{test data, some more data}, some text, some more text
```

by wrapping the said field in {} as this is the delimiter the latex package understands.

Is there a way to tell pandas.to_csv to do this?

I have tried the following

```
df.to_csv(new_filename, index = False, header=False, quotechar='{')
```

But of course it closes the text wrap with '{' when I need '}'

**Update**
When I wrote the csv file using pandas.to.csv I used a sep of "|" knowing that I wouldn't have that in my survey responses text. The latex csv table package was able to handle delimited "| csv files.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose a workaround. Alter the dataframe's columns containing commas by adding prefix `'{'` and suffix `'}'`. Then tell `pandas.to_csv` to not quote columns at all.

```
import csv

df['column containing commas'] = '{' + df['column containing commas'] + '}'
df.to_csv(..., quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, ...)
```